# How to explore HBase data

Tags: solr, apache-spark, hbase

I am currently doing an app that loads data into HBase, I chose HBase because the data is not structured and therefore using a column based database is recommended. 
Once the data is in HBase I thought of integrating Solr to it but I found little information about the subject and no answer for my question "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36542936/integrating-solr-to-hbase" 
So I wanted to ask how I can query data stored in HBase? Spark Streaming doesn't seem to be made for that .. 
Any help please ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your question is on how to query data from Hbase.

- [Apache Phoenix](https://phoenix.apache.org/) Provides a Sql Wrapper over Hbase.
- [Hive Hbase Integration](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HBaseIntegration) Hive also provides a Sql Wrapper over Hbase
- [Spark Hbase Plugin](https://github.com/nerdammer/spark-hbase-connector) lets your Apache Spark application interact with Apache HBase.

Comment: thank you, what about Solr ? any idea if it's useful to query data in HBase and use it ?

Comment: If Its just to query data I think Phoenix is the best option It also supports secondary indexes and is pretty easy to setup. 
I haven't worked with solr and hbase. But you might want to look into these Projects [SolBase](https://github.com/Photobucket/Solbase) and [Lily](http://www.lilyproject.org/lily/index.html). Not sure if they provide hbase as a storage layer or do they support Integration.

Comment: Also go through this post [Solr to Query Hbase](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14759778/using-solr-to-query-hbase). They have some interesting comments you should go through.